# Dashboard last 5 order details missing

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, sales-order, dashboard

My store was working fine earlier today, but I don't know why and how my dashboard just stopped showing the details of last 5 orders now.Here it is http://s32.postimg.org/7i1hvcmgl/dash.jpg

Comment: please upgrade your question not proper what you want to display or missing.